# Why does one polygon disappear when merging in edit mode?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, merge, qgis-2.6

I want to merge some polygons into one using the merge tool. But when doing so, one of the polygons just disappears (see screenshot 2). Why does this happen?
When I use the simplify tool before, it does not happen.

My system: QGIS 2.6.0; Linux Mint 17

[image: merge tool]

[image: polygon right bottom disappeared]

Comment: Does it disappear at all scales when zooming in and out?

Comment: Yes, it does appear also in different zooming

Comment: I would run a geometry check on that shape (or the entire file) to start with and make sure it's valid with no errors.

Comment: Yes vektor>geometry tools>check geometry did it! Two polygons had crossings within themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specific shapes exhibit strange behavior as a result of a geoprocessing tool or editing operation, one of the first things to check is whether they have valid geometries. Geometry errors can result in null results or other errors. QGIS has a Check Geometry Validity tool, and another option would be to load it into GRASS and run v.clean. There are several tools available in other software as well.